# join multiple mysql table with prefix and group sum

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have three mysql tables have achieved to have all invoices from the orders table along with Invoice_No_Amt - Refund_Amount, group sum of settlement value

Now I would like to have fullname column from sku_mapping table also to be listed in the result. prefix_sku is the primary key in sku_mapping table

fk_orders

```
|order_item_id |order_id    |Invoice_No       |Invoice_No_Amt  |Qty   |Refund_Qty |Refund_Amount | sku
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1131231       |123         |F08OTTN16-1      |100            |1     |            |              |A3001
|1113138       |321         |F08OTTN16-2      |200            |2     |1           |200           |B1001
|1231231       |023         |F08OTTN16-3      |100            |1     |1           |100           |C2001
|1133138       |320         |F08OTTN16-4      |200            |2     |            |              |D8901
|1134231       |103         |F08OTTN16-5      |100            |1     |            |              |E6210
|1113538       |300         |F08OTTN16-6      |200            |2     |            |              |F1001
|1003538       |300         |F08OTTN16-7      |200            |2     |            |              |G9003
```

fk_payments

```
|order_item_id    |order_id    |Invoice_No       |Invoice_No_Amt |Settlement Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|OI:1131231       |123         |F08OTTN16-1      |100            |40
|OI:1113138       |321         |F08OTTN16-2      |200            |150
|OI:1231231       |023         |F08OTTN16-3      |100            |-50
|OI:1133138       |320         |F08OTTN16-4      |200            |200
|OI:1134231       |103         |F08OTTN16-5      |100            |40
|OI:1113538       |300         |F08OTTN16-6      |200            |250
|OI:1131231       |123         |F08OTTN16-1      |100            |40
|OI:1133138       |320         |F08OTTN16-4      |200            |100
|OI:1113138       |321         |F08OTTN16-2      |200            |-200
```

sku_mapping

```
|prefix_sku |full_name 
-------------------
f|A3001     |Apple_Phone
f|B1001     |Belkin
f|C2001     |Cat_Access
f|D8901     |Dlink
f|E6210     |Eltron
f|F1001     |Flag
f|G9003     |gott
a|A3001     |Apple_Phone
a|B1001     |Belkin
a|C2001     |Cat_Access
a|D8901     |Dlink
a|E6210     |Eltron
a|F1001     |Flag
a|G9003     |gott
```

query

```
select o.*,
       (coalesce(Refund_Amount, 0) + coalesce(sv, 0)) as SettledAmount,
       (Invoice_No_Amt - coalesce(Refund_Amount, 0) - coalesce(sv, 0)) as netAmount
from fk_orders o left join
     (select invoice_no, sum(Settlement_Value) as sv
      from fk_payments
      group by invoice_no
     ) p
     on o.invoice_no = p.invoice_no;
```

guess this is statement be incorporated in the above code to get prefix_sku from sku_mapping table but dono how to have where statement in join

concat ('f|',O.`f|sku`)=conso.conso

Comment: Can you provide the desire output with this data? That will help a lot. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to add "where condition" in join , you can do it by specifying as a join criteria, for example

```
select * 
from A 
join B 
  on A.id = B.id 
 and B.id > 4000 ;
```